# Dual monitor set up using DVI and HDMI

Tags: video, hdmi, dvi

My desktop comes with a DVI port and a HDMI port.

I currently have a monitor connected to DVI port and it works fine.

I'm wondering if I can use the remaining HDMI port for a second monitor.

I heard somewhere that you can't use HDMI with DVI, so I wanted to make sure if I can have HDMI and DVI to have a dual monitor set up.

Thank you.

Comment: most likely what you heard was that video cards that have two standard outputs (VGA/DVI or DVI/DVI) as well as an HDMI output can only have two monitors connected at any one time... any combination, but never all three.  There are some video cards that are specifically made to use all three, but as it turns out for most of them the HDMI shares a clock generator with one of the DVI outputs, so it's actually just two ports for the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work just fine; I am using this exact same setup myself. I am using Windsows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, but this setup should work with any recent version of Windows.